# Bootstrap template based on RTL direction - FLIP HORIZONTAL

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap v4.0.0 template which is LTR direction, I want to change whole template to RTL Direction, I used these following methods:

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body dir="rtl" >
body { direction:rtl; }
html { direction:rtl; }
https://github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/bootstrap-v4-rtl (bootstrap-rtl.css)
```

but these methods not working.

**

> **What's the best way to completely change page direction like a mirror**
>   **FLIP HORIZONTAL? (RTL Direction)**

**

> This following CSS code, it will change direction of page based on
>   Flip Horizontal, but how to reservse it after that? (**Please have a**
>   **look into image in below**)

```
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
-ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
filter: fliph; /*IE*/
```

[image: How to do it with CSS?]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet flips/mirrors the page horizontally by reversing the horizontal scale

```css
.mirror{
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mirror">
mirrored text
</div>
<div>
not mirrored
</div>
```

Comment: This method is good, but there's something, as you know, mirror side is flip horizontal but how can we rotate it to correct way that we will be able to read texts ?

Comment: as for your update (didn't see that untill now) try looking at the source code for this site: http://www.messletters.com/en/mirrored/